# I need help in my app : about to path all code and update, post and delete methods are not working using postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, function, api

I am facing some issues in my app:

- The `post`, `put`, and `delete` methods are not working when using postman
- I don't know exactly how to path the rest of the code below after the `delete` method, they work in a browser, but only if I paste them on the top

I am open for any kind of suggestion that can help me to improve these codes.

Thank you for your help.

---

***index.js:***

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const dishes = require("./api/dishes");

const port = process.env.PORT || 7000;

app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/dishes", dishes);

// make the server listen to requests
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}!`));
```

***dishes.js:***

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const pool = require("./../database");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);

//get All dishes
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let mysql = "SELECT * FROM dishe";
  let query = pool.query(mysql, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        status: 200,
        error: null,
        response: results
      })
    );
  });
});

//==== Add a new dishe
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const meal = req.body;
  console.log("dishe:", dishe);
  pool.query("INSERT into dishe SET ?", dishe, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.send(error);
    }
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        status: 200,
        error: null,
        response: results
      })
    );
  });
});

// get a dishe by id
app.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  let mysql = "SELECT * FROM dishe WHERE dishe.id=" + req.params.id;
  let query = pool.query(mysql, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        status: 200,
        error: null,
        response: results
      })
    );
  });
});

//==== Update a dishe by id

app.put("/", (req, res) => {
  let mysql =
    "UPDATE dishe SET id='" +
    req.body.id +
    "', title='" +
    req.body.title +
    "', description='" +
    req.body.description +
    "',location='" +
    req.params.location +
    "', when='" +
    req.body.when +
    "', max_reservation='" +
    req.body.max_reservations +
    "', price='" +
    req.body.price +
    "', create_date='" +
    req.body.created_date;
  let query = pool.query(mysql, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        status: 200,
        error: null,
        response: results
      })
    );
  });
});

//==== Delete a dishe by id

app.delete("/", (req, res) => {
  let mysql = "DELETE FROM dishe WHERE id=" + req.params.id + "";
  let query = pool.query(mysql, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        status: 200,
        error: null,
        response: results
      })
    );
  });
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query);
  const { maxPrice } = req.query;
  const { availableReservations } = req.query;
  const { title } = req.query;
  const { createdAfter } = req.query;
  const { limit } = req.query;

  //==== Get dishes that has a price smaller than maxPrice
  if (maxPrice) {
    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM dishe WHERE price < ${maxPrice}`, function(
      error,
      results,
      fields
    ) {
      // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
      if (error) throw error;
      // results will contain the results of the query
      res.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          status: 200,
          error: null,
          response: results
        })
      );
    });
  }

  //==== Get dishes that still has available reservations
  else if (availableReservations) {
    pool.query(
      `SELECT dishe.id, total_reservations, max_reservations from dishe inner join
      (select SUM(reservation.number_of_guests) total_reservations, dishe_id from reservation group by reservation.meal_id) res
        on dishe.id = dishe_id AND dishe.max_reservations > res.total_reservations;`,
      function(error, results, fields) {
        // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
        if (error) throw error;
        // results will contain the results of the query
        res.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            status: 200,
            error: null,
            response: results
          })
        );
      }
    );
  }
  //Get dishes that partially match a title.

  else if (title) {
    pool.query(
      `SELECT title,
      description
      FROM dishe
      WHERE description 
      regexp 'Tag|Cav|Cas'`,
      function(error, results, fields) {

        // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query

        if (error) throw error;

        // results will contain the results of the query

        res.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            status: 200,
            error: null,
            response: results
          })
        );
      }
    );
  }

  //==== Get dishes that has been created after the date

  else if (createdAfter) {
    pool.query(
      `SELECT * FROM dishe WHERE created_date > '${createdAfter}'`,
      function(error, results, fields) {
        // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
        if (error) throw error;
        // results will contain the results of the query
        res.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            status: 200,
            error: null,
            response: results
          })
        );
      }
    );
  }

  //==== Only specific number of dishes

  else if (limit) {
    pool.query(
      `SELECT dishe.id,
          dishe.title
          FROM dishe
          LIMIT ${limit}`,
      function(error, results, fields) {

        // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query

        if (error) throw error;

        // results will contain the results of the query

        res.send(
          JSON.stringify({
            status: 200,
            error: null,
            response: results
          })
        );
      }
    );
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: So the code works in browser but not postman, have you tried updating the URL to match both? Not sure what your issue is here, yet

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is that the code works in the browser with the get method, but with update,  put and delete is not the case. Also the code below from maxPrice I don't how to do the path so it can work all together in the browser.

Comment: Wait... are you saying the `update`, `put`, and `delete` are not working *in the browser*? Browsers can only send `get` requests (from the "URL bar" at the top)

Comment: Start with simpler code and see, if you can make it working in postman: replace post route with simpler one, like `app.post("/", (req, res) => { res.send("POST is here"); });`. When you get it working and seeing the response in postman, then make it more complex, like `app.post("/", (req, res) => { res.send(req.body); });` and try to send and receive back the body of POST request. Then you will see that routing is OK in general, then you are better off to figure out what is not working in your DB etc.

Comment: @Matt Oestreich, I have used postman for post, put and delete. Unfortunatly is not working.

Comment: Does your server throw any errors? What happens if you comment out the code within those routes and just respond with something simple (exactly what @HeroQu is suggesting) -- I wouldn't be surprised if it had something to do with your database.

Comment: @Hero Qu same result, I don't know what to do. Thanks for your advice

Comment: @MattOestreich in postman app I got this error: {
    "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "INSERT into meal SET ?"
}

Comment: But... doesn't that tell you what the exact problem is? You have an issue with your SQL query... try commenting out ALL of the code in the route and respond with something simple. Have you tried just removing the "?" from the query?? `INSERT into dishe SET ?"` you have a `?` in your query.

Comment: Also, doing something like this `let mysql = "SELECT * FROM dishe WHERE dishe.id=" + req.params.id;` will lead to a **VERY, VERY** bad time for you.. You are leaving yourself ***WIDE OPEN*** to SQL Injection.

Comment: I have remove the ?, but nothing change. Ok, let me try it out and see....

Comment: let mysql = "SELECT * FROM meal WHERE meal.id=" + req.params.id this one is working very well in the browser and in postman aswell.

Comment: I have tried to modify my code like this :app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  let data = {
    id: req.body.id,
    number_of_guests: req.body.number_of_guests,
    dishe_id: req.body.dishe_id,
    created_date: req.body.created_date
  };
  let mysql = "INSERT INTO dishe SET ?";
  let query = pool.query(mysql, data, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
      "status": 200,
      "error": null,
      "response": results
    }));
  });
});

Comment: I am getting this error : incorrect datetime value 2019-08-14T22:00:00.000Z for column created_at at row 1. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Fred no problem - you should do some research/Google about "*sanitizing input for SQL queries in Nodejs*" or Google "*parameterize SQL queries Nodejs*" or "*mitigate SQL injection Nodejs*".. you get the idea..  There's plenty out there on how to mitigate SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes, I got the idea